# How do I prevent group Items from collapsing when my screen is smaller or on mobile view, here I mean when it is really small

Tags: css, angular2-template

I'm trying to prevent my group of three icons from collapsing to a vertical state, currently they are align horizontally, the problem is when i adjust the screen to a smaller one, the icons will readjust as well when my screen reaches a certain size

```html
<div class="">
  <div class="list-item">
    <section class="row">
      <vehicleHeading [vehicleItem]="vehicleItem" class="col-md-10 col-sm-9 col-xs-8 nopadding"></vehicleHeading>

      <div class="icon-group col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
        <span class="pull-right">
          <i [id]="mapId" (click)="showVehicleOnMap()" class="material-pin pointer nopaddingLeft"></i>
          <span [id]="collapseId" (click)="showVehicleDetails()"><i  class="material-list pointer"></i></span>
          <collapsibleImage [id]="detailsId" (collapseEvent)="onToggleClick($event)"></collapsibleImage>
        </span>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>

  <div [collapse]="isCollapsed" class="panel-body topBorder">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-7 col-lg-7">
        <div class="form form-horizontal hidden">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
              <div class="pull-right">
                <i class="viewMore">Details</i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-lg-5 nopadding">
        <div class="pull-right thumbnail">
          <vehicleMap id="vehicleMapId" #mapDetails [VehicleDetails]="vehicleItem"></vehicleMap>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try wrapping them with a `div` that has `display: inline-flex; `

Comment: @user5014677 still behaves the same way